# How to handle Twitter authentication?

Tags: twitter, laravel-4

I'm trying to integrate a functionality in a webapp, where a user clicks a button to tweet how awesome the webapp is. (I know, I know, stupid, but hey, the boss wants it)

I set up the route below using Thujohn's Twitter for Laravel 4 - https://github.com/thujohn/twitter-l4

```
Route::get('/twitter/callback', function() {
    // You should set this route on your Twitter Application settings as the callback
    // https://apps.twitter.com/app/YOUR-APP-ID/settings
    if(Session::has('oauth_request_token')) {
        $request_token = array(
            'token' => Session::get('oauth_request_token'),
            'secret' => Session::get('oauth_request_token_secret'),
        );

        Twitter::set_new_config($request_token);

        $oauth_verifier = FALSE;
        if(Input::has('oauth_verifier')) {
            $oauth_verifier = Input::get('oauth_verifier');
        }

        // getAccessToken() will reset the token for you
        $token = Twitter::getAccessToken( $oauth_verifier );
        if( !isset( $token['oauth_token_secret'] ) ) {
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_error', 'We could not log you in on Twitter.');
        }

        $credentials = Twitter::query('account/verify_credentials');
        if( is_object( $credentials ) && !isset( $credentials->error ) ) {
            // $credentials contains the Twitter user object with all the info about the user.
            // Add here your own user logic, store profiles, create new users on your tables...you name it!
            // Typically you'll want to store at least, user id, name and access tokens
            // if you want to be able to call the API on behalf of your users.

            // This is also the moment to log in your users if you're using Laravel's Auth class
            // Auth::login($user) should do the trick.

            var_dump($credentials);

            //return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_notice', "Congrats! You've successfully signed in!");
        }
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_error', 'Crab! Something went wrong while signing you up!');
    }
});
```

However, I don't really know what I should do in this part:

```
// $credentials contains the Twitter user object with all the info about the user.
// Add here your own user logic, store profiles, create new users on your tables...you name it!
// Typically you'll want to store at least, user id, name and access tokens
// if you want to be able to call the API on behalf of your users.

// This is also the moment to log in your users if you're using Laravel's Auth class
// Auth::login($user) should do the trick.
```

What do I need to do to make sure a user doesn't need to authenticate himself every time?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the $credentials object, you should see oauth access tokens. Save these along with your user data (username, email, name, etc) in your database, and you can use them next time you make a call to the twitter API.

Comment: Add a package like raveren/kint to instpect the full class -- they may not be public properties and only available through a method like getToken() or similar.  a Kint dump would show you the available methods you can use to pull this information out.